# Installing cuda 8.0 in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, cuda

I have been trying to install cuda 8.0 in ubuntu 20.04.
I used the documentation provided in: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-80-ga2-download-archive
I tried with both the deb(local) and deb(network).
However, using `sudo apt-get cuda`, I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
cuda : Depends: cuda-11-0 (>= 11.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

From a few other questions I got to know, I could use `sudo apt-get cuda-8-0`.
However that too shows following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-8-0 : Depends: cuda-runtime-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: cuda-demo-suite-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can anyone help what I am doing wrong and how I can install Cuda-8-0 in ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Is there a specific reason that makes you install Cuda 8.0? Cuda 8.0 is only compatible with Ubuntu 16.04 and 14.04 (according to the same website you mentioned) and they both reached their End Of Life. Why you don't try the steps in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1251052/822295) for Cuda 10.1

Comment: There is a package that only works can only run on CUDA 8.0. I was wondering if I can use the package while using ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I am afraid this will not work for you, I even tried to install Cuda 10.1 using the deb files on Ubuntu 20.04 but it didn't work. The only solution, as for now, is to run `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit` which will install Cuda 10.1

Comment: I couldn't make CUDA 8 to run on ubuntu 20.04, so I reverted back to 18.04, using a clean install. Then I found this wonderful resource : https://rodrigodzf.github.io/setup/cuda/2019/04/15/cuda-setup.html. Using this I was able to again install CUDA-8.0 in ubuntu 18.04. I am not sure if the similar procedure works in ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Well I am not sure if it will work on 20.04 or not, all I can tell is that the deb file (10.1) didn't work for me..

Comment: For people who say "Why not switch to CUDA 10.x" please note that setting up CUDA properly involves compatibility between OS version, driver version, supported CUDA version for the given dev tools and supported CUDA version for the GPU. It's not so trivial to just switch.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install CUDA 8.0 on Ubuntu 22 using the runfile and gcc-5, see [CUDA 8 and GCC 5 on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1442001/1179344)

It should be more or less equivalent for Ubuntu 20. (Probably, the kernel patch will need less changes).